# Replace alphabets with asteriks in typescript

Tags: typescript

I am working in angular and I have one string in format ABC1234567. I want to represent all alphabets in this string replaced with asterik. I may get another string as ABCD1234567. I can have n number of alphabets in my string. How can I represent alphabets in string as asteriks. something like this ***1234567.

Comment: Do you need to replace only latin characters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
console.log("ABC1234567".replace(/[a-z]/gi,"*"))
```

Answer (score 1):

use regex on the string

```
console.log('ABC1234567'.replace(/[a-zA-Z]/g, '*')); --> "***1234567"
```